# Returning a pointer to a vector element

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out best way to hold a pointer to an element in a vector that has just been created and added to the member variable vector:

```
  SceneGraphNode* addChild(std::string name){
    SceneGraphNode child(this,name);
    m_children.push_back(child);
    return &child;
}
```

The compiler rightfully gives me a warning since I am returning the address of an object created on the stack, and that object will go out of scope as the function ends. However, the object lives on in the `vector`, right?

So, should I ignore the warning or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> However, the object lives on in the vector, right?

No, a copy of it does.  You want to return the address of the copy.

```
return &m_children.back();
```

However, it is not a good idea to store a pointer to an object that resides in a vector.  Because when the vector needs to reallocate, the pointer will be invalidated.  Perhaps you should store pointers (preferably smart pointers) in your vector instead.

For example:

```
// in your class
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SceneGraphNode>> m_children;

SceneGraphNode* addChild(std::string name)
{
    std::unique_ptr<SceneGraphNode> child(new SceneGraphNode(this,name));
    m_children.push_back(std::move(child));
    return m_children.back().get();
}
```

Comment: yes, i'm going to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SceneGraphNode>> m_children;` instead

Comment: Or save the index of the element.

Comment: perhaps this should be another question, but it's super quick, how would I access member functions on `SceneGraphNode` using an iterator to this new `vector `of `unique_ptr`? The `iterator` is a pointer to another pointer, right?

Comment: @Fellowshee: `(**it).func()` or `(*it)->func()` -- It's not a pointer to a pointer, but it has similar behavior to one.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the object lives on in the vector, right?

When you push into vector, it actually push `copies` of the objects, not the object itself, into the vector. STL containers does `copy in, copy out`. However, as indicated by the compiler, you should not `return the address of an object created on the stack`.

Answer (score 0):

When adding it to the std::vector, you're essentially doing a copy. You should return the reference to the object stored in the vector.

```
return &(m_children.back());
```

Comment: Wow, it surprises me, but I actually find the brackets made it harder to read the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The object doesn't exactly live on in the vector, since when you are `push_back`ing it, you are making a *copy* of this element.

This code could work if you changed the return by something like that (Ryan's form would actually be more straightforward):

```
return &m_children[m_children.size() - 1];
```

That way, you are effectively returning a pointer to an element living in your vector.