# Removing an element from std::list of std::unique_pointer

Tags: c++, std, unique-ptr

According to this thread [Returning a pointer to a vector element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391331/returning-a-pointer-to-a-vector-element) , it is recommended to use the following code when inserting an object into a vector and returning its pointer:

```
// in your class
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SceneGraphNode>> m_children;

SceneGraphNode* addChild(std::string name)
{
    std::unique_ptr<SceneGraphNode> child(new SceneGraphNode(this,name));
    myList.push_back(std::move(child));
    return myList.back().get();
}
```

I plan to use the same code, but with a `std::list`. I don't have the problem with reallocation then, but `std::unique_ptr` still help upon destruction of the vector - instead of plain `delete`.

**Question:** How do I use list's `remove` with this setup? With plain pointers, I could just write `myList.remove(myPtr)`, where `myPtr` is a plain pointer to the object to remove.

Comment: Please note that even with the whole reallocation-on-resize thing with `std::vector`, it is often still plain faster than `std::list` (although you don't really have data locality here with the `std::unique_ptr`s).

Comment: @rubenvb you still gain additional data locality by not having to do two pointer dereferences to access an element. Halving your number of dereferences can have a significant impact depending on the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still do `myList.remove(myPtr)` if `myPtr` is a `unique_ptr`.  This is because `operator==` is overloaded for such smart pointers: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_cmp

Comment: But this would require that I build a second `unique_ptr` to `myPtr` before calling the remove method: `myList.remove(unique_ptr(myPtr))` . Isn't that a problem?

Comment: @Michael You just need a reference to the `unique_ptr` you are trying to remove from the list. Then `operator==` returns true when the `unique_ptr` is compared to itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a plain pointer as myPtr you can use

```
myList.remove_if([myPtr](const std::unique_ptr<SceneGraphNode>& ptr){return ptr.get() == myPtr});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this will be helpful:

```
it = find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), name);
if (it != myList.end())
{
   mylist.erase(it);
}
```